# A question about the antiperiodic conditions in string theory

Tags: string-theory, boundary-conditions

We know that for both bosonic and fermionic strings, there are possibly antiperiodic boundary conditions:
$$X^\mu(\tau,\sigma+2\pi)=-X^\mu(\tau,\sigma); \tag 1\\$$
$$\Psi(\tau,\sigma+2\pi)=-\Psi(\tau,\sigma). \tag2 $$
Eq.(1) can be interpreted as a string moving in a orbifold while Eq.(2) is simply the Neveu-Schwarz sector for fermionic strings. But I really find it uncomfortable to accept such anti-periodic conditions. For Eq.(1), is the orbifold physically real? For Eq.(2), how can the field (though fermionic) on the string be double-valued?

Comment: What do you mean by "physically real"?  For the second question, this has nothing to do with string theory - how do you get a classical Dirac spinor field where a full rotation gives a minus sign in general? ("Double-valuedness" is usually a sign of some non-trivial bundles in the rigorous formulation, and sure enough, defining spinor fields rigorously requires the notion of sections of the [spinor bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor_bundle).

Comment: @ACuriousMind, Thank you very much for your comment. It really helps me to get a feeling for the antiperiodic conditions. Now the Mobius strip provide an example where for one start point $p$ with angle$-\pi$ can have $\pi$ after a round of the strip. But we can naturally identify $-\pi$ and $\pi$ because they are angular coordinates. Now for Eq.(1),  is the identification to obtain the orbifold natural? I mean, is it really possible to have a orbifold as one of our spacetime dimensions.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I think it is possible to have a orbifold when we can naturally accept the compactified dimension. No problem, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "have an orbifold as one of our spacetime dimensions" - the orbifold is usually the internal space in most models, i.e. the compactified part, but surely you can also have all of space be an orbifold. Are you asking whether it is theoretically or phenomenologically possible? Also, those two questions - "how are non-periodic boundary conditions possible?" and "is an orbifold a possible model for our universe?" (or whatever exactly you want to ask) are two distinct questions and should be asked separately (at least the former makes for a good question, I'd say).

Answer (score 1):

The question involves orbifolds in general that map a string according to a discrete group $\Gamma$ as $X^i~\rightarrow~\theta^{ij}X^j~+~x^i$, for the indices $i,~j~>~3$ on the compactified manifold. The string or particle propagates on a space $M^4\times C$ in twisted theory. The space $C$, a Calabi-Yau space, is of the form $\mathbb R^6/S$, such that $S$ is a space group, similar to solid state physics, and that $\tau~=~S/\Gamma$ has the symmetry of a torus and is a twist that defines the orbifold on a torus $\mathbb T^6/\tau$.

The twists in the $6$-dimensional space induce $\psi(\sigma~+~2\pi)~=~\gamma\psi(\sigma)$, for $\gamma$ an element of the discrete group $\Gamma$. The complex valued string coordinates $Z^j~=~(X^{2j}~+~X^{2j+1})/\sqrt 2$ for $j~=~\{2,~3,~4\}$ satisfy the periodicity conditions
$$
Z^j(\sigma~+~2\pi)~=~e^{2\pi i(\phi_j+\theta}Z^j(\sigma).
$$
Here the phase term $\theta~=~0$ in the Ramond sector and $\theta~=~1/2$ in the Neveu-Schwarz sector. This induces a phase shift on the field as
$$
\psi^j(\sigma~+~2\pi)~=~e^{2\pi i(\phi_j+\theta)}\psi^j(\sigma),
$$
so that with compactification and reduction to $4$ dimensions the twisting theory of the string on an orbifold induces this phase shift.

This a simple look at the situation. In the NS sector the phase shift for $\phi_j~=~0$ is $\psi^j(\sigma~+~2\pi)$ $=~e^{\pi i}\psi^j(\sigma)$ $=~-\psi^j(\sigma)$.  This twisting is a form of $T$-duality and the Moebius or linear fractional transformation of a string which relates the mode number to the winding number of the string on the compactified manifold, a Calabi-Yau space or D-brane.

Comment: You're not answering the question. The question asks *how* a field can be multi-valued on the string as in those boundary conditions (since $\sigma$ and $\sigma+2\pi$ are really the same point in the string), while you simply wrote down again *which* boundary conditions they fulfill.